# Partial Save in Spring Boot Application while using ConstraintValidator

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a Spring Boot application, in which I am validating a list of my object in payload. It works perfectly. But the requirement is to save the object which has proper values. Is it possible to do with ConstraintValidator or just to validate in the Service layer?

```
public class NumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NumberRegex, String> {

@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if(value != null && value.length() > 1) {
        String regEx = "^((?!(0)|(\\d+11))[0-9]{3,6})$";
        return value.matches(regEx);
    }
    return false;
}


@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = NumberValidator.class)
public @interface NumberRegex {
    String message() default "Number should not start with 0. Number length should be from 3 to 6 digits.";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Object:

```
@JsonProperty("number")
@NumberRegex
private String number;
```

Sample Payload:

```
{
   "numbers": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "number": 425 
        },
        {
           "id": 2,
           "number": 011
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above payload, the id 1 needs to be saved as it has valid number. I just want to ignore the id with the value 2.
Appreciate if someone can help on this.